# Radial Gradient using "farthest-side" over Background Image doesn't work on Safari

Tags: angular, sass, angular-cli, postcss, radial-gradients

Here's the code:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom right, #fb5816, #025bbb), url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200') center center no-repeat;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

It works on Chrome and Firefox without a problem, but not on Safari. Note that I have this written in `scss` and I'm building my project using `angular-cli` so I'm supposing that PostCSS kicks in to generate what needs to be for all browsers. No?